# MySQL performance - do joining using compsite key increase performance?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have two table with millions of data on it. both table has 2 parameter by which I want to join those tables. query example :

```
SELECT 
    bills.meter_id,
    records.record_id
FROM records
JOIN bills ON (
    bills.mnumber = records.mnumber
    AND bills.end_date = records.enddate
)
WHERE records.mnumber IS NOT NULL
AND records.enddate IS NOT NULL
```

So as you can see I have two tables **records** and **bills** which join using **mnumber** and **endate** fields. currently none of these columns are indexed. What is the best index combination which give best performance for this query. Will `GROUP BY records.mnumber,records.enddate` help performance?

Comment: Always join on an indexed ID. I don't understand why you join on date. And you have `end_date` and `enddate`. I know they are different fields but you should stick to one notation and not write fields differently.

Comment: "Will GROUP BY records.mnumber,records.enddate help performance?" No and it will mess up your query results if you just add it assuming the server isn't running in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

Comment: For better answers you can better share your table structures and some example data.  And expected results..

Comment: @DanFromGermany yeah, it was not my schema so its named that way. but I only need to join with these both column as I want matching results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I suggested GROUP BY as I want only one match for join, other column of table are not important as it will not help on joining the table.

Comment: " I suggested GROUP BY as I want only one match for join" `SELECT bills.meter_id,
    records.record_id ... GROUP BY records.mnumber,records.enddat` is just a plain wrong SQL query because the SELECT is using columns that are not in the GROUP BY .. Besides using `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates doesn't make sense without aggregated functions (like `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MAX` or `MIN`) in mine opinion.. i would use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `JOIN` (but not `LEFT JOIN`), first see which table is likely to benefit from an indx for filtering.  Since `WHERE` only refers to `records`, that is likely to  be the first table the Optimizer will use.

```
WHERE records.mnumber IS NOT NULL
  AND records.enddate IS NOT NULL
```

may benefit from `INDEX(mnumber, enddate)` -- in either order.  It depends on how much of the table has both of the columns being `NULL`.

Moving on to the next table (`bills`):

```
 ON bills.mnumber  = records.mnumber
AND bills.end_date = records.enddate
```

will definitely benefit from this composite index on `bills`:

```
INDEX(mnumber, enddate)  -- in either order
```

(I agree with the other Answer about `GROUP BY`.)

Answer (score 0):

> Will GROUP BY records.mnumber,records.enddate help performance?

`GROUP BY` is manipulating your resultset - it's for aggregation, not for performance...

You are chosing between 3 options:

1. Optimize your schema and make proper IDs, not joining on a date field
2. Add an index to the date field
3. Add a compound index over both fields

To check what works best, use `EXPLAIN` before the queries and compare the output (less lookups usually means better performance).